# Data output varying for same query in different server

Tags: sql, firebird

I am validating firebird over open access commands. For validation, 
I use the same commands for both firebird and open access(SQL) over same data and schema. when I ran this query on SQL, it is working. In case, of group queries, it is not showing desired output. How firebird evaluates a correlated query?

```
SELECT EMPNO,SAL
FROM EMP E 
WHERE 1 = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO) 
           FROM DEPT D 
           WHERE E.ENAME like '%AME%') 
OR EMPNO = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)
            FROM DEPT D 
            WHERE E.ENAME like  (SELECT TOP 1 ENAME 
                                 FROM emp E1 
                                 WHERE E1.EMPNO=D.DEPTNO)) 
ORDER BY EMPNO;
```

Here are the outputs for open access(SQL),

```
EMPNO   SAL 
-15 3000    
-12 2000    
-11 100500.55   
-10 NULL    
-9  1111.11 
-8  -3000   
-6  NULL    
  .........
  .........
Rows selected = 27
```

Firebird,

```
EMPNO   SAL 

Rows selected = 0
```

Even though Firebird, Openacess(SQL) uses same structured language but differ in outputs.

DDL of the query,

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(EMPNO integer , ENAME varchar(32) , JOB varchar(32) , HIREDATE datetime , SAL float ,COMM real ,DEPTNO integer); 
CREATE TABLE DEPT(DEPTNO integer, DNAME varchar(40), LOC varchar(40), DIVNO integer);
```

Data for above DDL,

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(101, 'NAME1', 'TITLE1', '1990-02-02 02:02:02', 100500.55,  2000.90,  1);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (102,'NAME2','TITLE2', '1958-02-02 02:02:02',2000.00, 20000.00, 1);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(103, 'NAME3', 'TITLE3', '1997-03-12 08:09:54', 3000.00,  1000.50, 2);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(104, 'NAME4', 'TITLE4', '1997-04-02 00:00:00', 1111.11, 2.22, 1);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(105, 'NAME5', 'TITLE5', '1997-06-12 08:09:54', 3000.00, 1000.50, 2);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(106, 'NAME6', 'TITLE6', '1997-06-12 02:02:02', 1111.11, 2.22, 1);
INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC, DIVNO) Values (1, 'Software', 'San Jose', 10);
INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC, DIVNO) Values (2, 'Sales', 'LA', 20);
INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC, DIVNO) Values (3, 'Marketing', 'LA', 20);
```

Comment: Please format the query so it is readable (that query does not make sense to me BTW). Also post a reproducible example: include the DDL and a sample of the data. Have you checked that a simple `select * from emp` returns any data, and that those subqueries produce the expected results, do that the outer query will produce a anything.

Comment: Please provide the DDL of the tables involved and a sample of the data, and describe what this query is supposed to do, as it makes no sense at all to me (apart from the fact it would give a 'token unknown' error in Firebird).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It has more than 15 rows to insert. How can I show that  to you ?

Comment: What's this  "open access" thing? Also `OR EMPNO = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO) ..` does not make any sense. Why do you compare the `empno` to a `deptno`?

Comment: I am testing each and every possible correlated query over open access command and Firebird.

Comment: Create a reduced example that can be used to reproduce the problem, so that we can try it on our own machine and see what is going wrong. So create a database, populate it with a limited number of values, and post the DDL and DML you used to create that on this question after you have confirmed it can be used to reproduce it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel updated question with the data, can you please check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons that you don't get any information is simple, the data you have doesn't allow for any data to be returned. Lets dissect your query:

```
SELECT EMPNO,SAL
FROM EMP E
```

Select some fields from emp

```
WHERE 1 = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO) 
           FROM DEPT D 
           WHERE E.ENAME like '%AME%')
```

Where 1 must be equal to the max `DEPTNO` from `DEPT` if for the current row from `EMP` the field `ENAME` contains `AME` (note that this is case sensitive).

This means that the comparison is either `1 = null` (which is `null`, not false) or - with your sample data - `1 = 3` (which is false).

```
OR EMPNO = (SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)
            FROM DEPT D 
            WHERE E.ENAME like  (SELECT TOP 1 ENAME 
                                 FROM emp E1 
                                 WHERE E1.EMPNO=D.DEPTNO))
```

Or `EMPNO` is equal to the maximum of `DEPTNO` of `DEPT` with a convoluted query that makes no sense: you are querying the maximum `DEPTNO` where the `ENAME` of the current row of `EMP E` is equal to **any** first `ENAME` for where the `EMPNO` is equal to the current `DEPTNO` of `DEPT D` (which given the sample data is always false).

This query will always yield `null` because - in the sample data - the values in `EMPNO` are disjunct from `DEPTNO`, so the result of the innermost query is no row (yields null), so the first inner query will also yield `null`. Even if the first inner query had returned a value, the evaluation would still be false as `EMPNO` and `DEPTNO` are disjunct.

In other words, the `WHERE`-clause is equivalent to `WHERE FALSE OR NULL`, which yields no rows.

I have no idea what open access is (because a quick search doesn't reveal anything called that), but it seems to have very weird evaluation rules for SQL queries.

As I don't understand what this query is trying to retrieve, I also can't offer you a query that works.

Comment: Thanks , can I get documentation link for firebird3.0.

Comment: @kvk30 Note that this isn't really Firebird specific, this answer would apply to any normal RDBMS; the documentation for Firebird 3 is [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html) and [Firebird 3.0 Release Notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html) for the changes since 2.5.

Comment: Mark, If Firebird can create SQL environment then it should have some alternative, right?

Comment: @kvk30 I think you don't understand what SQL is, SQL or Structured Query Language, is a language defined in an ISO standard (ISO-9075) as a common language to be used by all relational databases. Firebird implements a subset of the standard (with some extensions), but it is the only language you can use to query Firebird (not 100% true, but close enough).